# From algo and DS book by narasimha karumanchi, i am not being able to understand the solution

Tags: data-structures, queue

A queue is set up in a circular array A[0..n-1] with front and rear defined as usual. Assume that n-1 locations in the array are available for storing the elements(with the other element being used to detect full/empty condition). Give formula for the number of elements in terms of rear,front and n.

i am getting the answer as, number of elements=rear-front+1 ; when rear>front
and number of elements=front-rear+1 when rear

the author states the answer as,
number of elements=rear-front+1 ; if rear==front and
number of elements=rear-front+n ; otherwise

Comment: You should give more information so that anybody can understand the question (even those that have not read the book). And please keep in mind that SO is not a code writing service: you should show what you have already done to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i am not being able to understand the way that extra element is going to behave. What is the use of that element, and how is to going to shift its position when enqueue or dequeue operations will be carried out.

Comment: I believe just a few read this book ( i havent). So please give a detailed view what the author said, may add some examples + images to explain that

Comment: Also, ive you want to add additional info, dont create an answer, edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

When queue is storied in array on circular manner, front index points to the first element and rear index points to the first free place (new element will be written at rear index)

If these indexes are equal, queue is considered empty.

When queue is filled with N (array size) elements, rear index reaches front index from the left size and they become equal - this situation is indistinguishable from the empty case. That is why in this paradigm one must leave single empty place and keep only N-1 elements in N-length array

It is worth to find the number of elements using rear, front and N by yourself  - very useful exercise. Consider cases when rear is right to front (simple case) and when it is left (wrapped case) and build common formula (recall integer modulo operation)

> i am getting the answer as, number of elements=rear-front+1 ; when
>   rear>front and number of elements=front-rear+1 when rear

You are wrong. Imagine that you have  single element. Front is 0, rear is 1 (place for the next element). So

```
 e is valid element
 f is front (and valid element)
 r is rear (no valid elelemnt)
 . is empty space

.feer...

Num = Rear - Front
```

Not consider wrapped situation.

```
 eer...fe
```

Rear is smaller than front. But we can virtually join array with itself

```
 eer...fe|eer...fe
```

and easily find that

```
Num = N + Rear - Front
```

Then combine results to get common formula working in all cases:

```
Num = (N + Rear - Front) % N    //integer modulo
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy by Narsimha Karumanchi (2017 edition) has a few minor errors. Based on the CS Stack Exchange reply [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80334/size-of-circular-queue/80339#80339),

```
number of the elements =              0,            if front == -1
                              rear - front + 1,     if rear >= front
                            N + rear - front + 1,   otherwise
```

A dry run of the formula with a queue of 5 elements:
Consider the following cases

1. rear = front = -1, i.e. empty queue, the output of the formula is 0.
2. rear = front = 0, i.e. rear = front, the output of the formula is 1.
3. rear = 4, front = 0, i.e. rear > front, the output of the formula is 5.
4. rear = 0, front = 4, i.e. rear < front, the output of the formula is 2